# Windows Search Service causing too many accessed files

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

I am trying to more closely audit my users access of files located on a file share. The files share is served by a server running windows server 2008 R2 and running the Windows Search Service. I am having  a problem with too many Event 4663's ("An attempt was made to access an object").

The problem occurs because when a user browses to a folder using windows explorer and then executes a search on the file share, the system generates an event 4663 for each result returned.

This may generate thousands of events within a minute. Is there any way for me to change the way the search hits are logged? Perhaps the search service could have its own user? Or can i disable the ability to full-text search?

Comment: How about getting rid of the search service altogether?

Comment: I think disabling the service would not prevent clients from executing a search on the file share. I might need a change to the Group Policy. But I am considering using Search Server Express in lieu of the search service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a group policy setting. Now when a user searches, the results are not logged as a file accessed.

> **Turn off the display of snippets in Content view**
>
> **Location**: User Configuration – Administrative Templates – Windows Components – Windows Explorer
>
> This policy lets you disable the
> display of file content snippets when
> Content view is turned on. Content
> view is the default view returned when
> a search is executed and shows
> snippets of content of returned files.
>
> **Default configuration:** Snippets are
> displayed in Content view
>
> **Purpose:** This policy should be enabled
> if you want to disable showing
> snippets of file contents by default
> when a search is returned. This helps
> users avoid displaying sensitive data accidentally through Windows Explorer searches while in a non-secure environment.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744697(WS.10).aspx#WS_TurnOffDisplayofSnippets